# Does Openshift limit loop?

Tags: openshift

I'm developing application on Openshift clound.

Please see this script:

```
 foreach ( $needle['tbody']['tr']['td'] as $key=>$values ){
      ....
      foreach( $values['table']['tr']['td'] as $value ){
        ....
        foreach ( $value['table']['tbody']['tr'] as $td_key => $td  ){

        }
        node_save($node);


$value['table']['tbody']['tr'] contains this values:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => tinh
                        )

                    [a] => Äá»“ng Nai
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [td] => 
                4K1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giai8
                        )

                    [div] => 27
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giai7
                        )

                    [div] => 490
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giai6
                        )

                    [div] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 9861
                            [1] => 3667
                            [2] => 9921
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giai5
                        )

                    [div] => 0262
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giai4
                        )

                    [div] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 95163
                            [1] => 89551
                            [2] => 99648
                            [3] => 39782
                            [4] => 69694
                            [5] => 09915
                            [6] => 90402
                        )

                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giai3
                        )

                    [div] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 57076
                            [1] => 54943
                        )

                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giai2
                        )

                    [div] => 07304
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giai1
                        )

                    [div] => 34882
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [td] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => giaidb
                        )

                    [div] => 339136
                )

        )

)
```

The foreach ( $value['table']['tbody']['tr'] as $td_key => $td  ){ ... loops only 2 times and cannot reach node_save($node);. I wonder if Openshift limit the loop ??
This script works fine on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see what is thrown in the logs.  Post any errors you see:  https://www.openshift.com/faq/how-to-troubleshoot-application-issues-using-logs

Comment: Php logs show error when I check condition of $td['td']['@attributes']['class']. After i comment all that checks, the foreach loops through all items in the array $value['table']['tbody']['tr'].

The error is PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array.
var_dump($td['td'])----> is array
var_dump($td['td]['@attributes']) ----> is array
var_dump($td['td]['@attributes']['class'])---> is array

.So, why php shows that error ?